# Create a numerical table from the values of a non numerical table

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
Backpack = {Potion = 'backpack',Stack = 'bag',Loot = 'derp', Gold = 'random'}

Backpack[1] ~= 'backpack' -- nope
```

As you guys can see, I cannot call Backpack[1] since its not a numeral table, how would I generate a table after the construction of Backpack, consisting only of it's values? for example:

```
Table_to_be_Constructed = {Value of Potion,Value of Stack,Value of Loot,Value of Gold} -- this is what i need
```

It seems simple but I couldn't find a way to do it.

I need it this way because i will run a numeric loop on Table_to_be_Constructed[i]

Comment: You can test like `Backpack.Potion ~= 'a'`. Would that work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over all the key-value pairs in a table, use the [pairs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-pairs) function:

```
local Table_to_be_Constructed = {}
for key, value in pairs(Backpack) do
    table.insert(Table_to_be_Constructed, value)
end
```

Note: the iteration order is not defined. So, you might want to sort `Table_to_be_Constructed` afterwards.

By convention, the variable name `_` is used to indicate a variable who's value won't be used. So, since you want only the values in the tables, you might write the loop this way instead:

```
for _, value in pairs(Backpack) do
```

---

#### For the updated question

`Backpack` has no order (The order in the constructor statement is not preserved.) If you want to add an order to its values when constructing `Table_to_be_Constructed`, you can do it directly like this:

```
local Table_to_be_Constructed = {
    Backpack.Potion, 
    Backpack.Stack, 
    Backpack.Loot, 
    Backpack.Gold
}
```

Or indirectly like this:

```
local items = { 'Potion', 'Stack', 'Loot', 'Gold' }
local Table_to_be_Constructed = {}
for i=1, #items do
    Table_to_be_Constructed[i] = Backpack[items[i]]    
end
```

Comment: yeah i have tried that before, but if Table_To_be_Constructed its not in sequence it won't help, how do i sort it based on Backpack?

Comment: In what way to you see an order or sequence in `Backpack`? (Place add this and the above info to your question.)

Comment: Sorry, i should have said that the values in Backpack are not alphabetical in any way